# Saving Image in Local Storage or AsyncStorage in React Native

Tags: image, file-upload, local-storage, persistence, asyncstorage

I am trying to save a profile image that I set through local function, but every time after refreshing or exiting the app the profile image gets reset to a default one that I set, my question is how after updating the image to store it to local storage and keep until next event change. I did use AsyncStorage but it not really keeping the change.

```
const {image, setImage} = React.useContext(AuthContext)
  const localStorage = "save-image"

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function getData () {
      try {
        const profileImg = await AsyncStorage.getItem(localStorage)
        return profileImg !== null ? JSON.parse(profileImg) : null
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
    getData()
  }, [])

 React.useEffect(() => {
  async function dataFetch () {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(localStorage, JSON.stringify(image))
   } catch (error) {
     console.log(error)
   }
  }
  dataFetch()
 }, [image])

  const choosingImageFromLocalImageLibrary = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    })
    console.log(result)

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result.uri);
    }
  }
```

I've tried setting Async storage as you can see above but still not working , maybe my implementation of async storage is bad or something else, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try AsyncStorage.setItem(localStorage, image), since your 'result.uri' is already a string

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).